# Using parent class constructor initialiser-list in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initializer-list

**ORIGINAL POST**

When compiled, the following code produces error C2436: '__ctor' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list

in Child.h

```
#include Parent.h
class  Child : public Parent  
{
    public:
        Child (List* pList) 
            : Parent::Parent(pList)
        {
        }
};
```

Here the parent class:

in Parent.h

```
class __declspec(dllimport) Parent : public GrandParent  
{
    public:
       Parent (List* pList = NULL);
}
```

in Parent.cpp

```
Parent::Parent (List* pList)
: 
    m_a(1)
   ,m_b(1)
   ,GrandParent(pList)
{
}
```

Isn't it right the way to make the Child class calling the Parent class constructor?

PS
Same happens if I split declaration and implementation of Child constructor into .h and .cpp. I cannot change the parent class code, as it is part of a pre-compiled library.

**AFTER YOUR SUGGESTIONS, @Mape, @Mat, @Barry, @Praetorian**

I realised the problem is due to the presence of another constructor in the Parent class. Thanks to your suggestions I generated the code reproducing the error (minimal, complete and verifiable) in a new post [Managing in Child class multiple constructors (with initializer-lists) of parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720199/managing-in-child-class-multiple-constructors-with-initializer-lists-of-parent[1])

Comment: You're doing it correctly in `Parent.cpp`, why do it differently in `Child`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The error is probably because of `Parent::Parent(pList)`, that should be `Parent(pList)`

Comment: Do you mean adding GrandParent code and relative includes? In my project I have to include the Parent .h and link a library, I cannot work on the full source as it is provided as a library. @Mat, do you mean splitting the code in .cpp and .h? If I use Parent instead of Parent::Parent, I have error  C2668: 'Parent::Parent' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

Comment: Repeating what Barry said, please post a [mcve]. You don't need multiple files or linking to whatever library to reproduce this error. A skeletal definition of `Child` and `Parent`, with the former inheriting from the latter, should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from your example, this compiles fine.
`Parent::Parent` should be just `Parent`.

```
#define NULL 0

struct List;

class GrandParent
{
    public:
       GrandParent(List* pList = NULL) {}
};


class Parent : public GrandParent
{
    public:
       Parent(List* pList = NULL);
       int m_a;
       int m_b;
};

Parent::Parent(List* pList)
:
    m_a(1)
   ,m_b(1)
   ,GrandParent(pList)
{
}

class  Child : public Parent
{
    public:
        Child (List* pList)
            : Parent(pList)
        {
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    GrandParent grandparent(NULL);
    Parent parent(NULL);
    Child child(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mape. I see you provided what I was asked for. The problem is that this code works and my one, splitted among files and partially embedded in libraries, doesn't. Thus, I have to deduce that the problem is not with the call syntax, but with the interplay of such files (inclues, external symbols)? There is also this weird "ambiguous call to ovetloaded function" error I have when using Child (List* pList) : Parent(pList).

Comment: Thanks @Mape. I added a new post refining the error, actually due to a second constructor I missed to mention... [here the new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720199/managing-in-child-class-multiple-constructors-with-initializer-lists-of-parent)