# Overloaded parent class constructors. Wrong inizializer choice?

Tags: constructor, parent-child, initializer-list, default-constructor, default-arguments

I would like to add a Child class to a pre-existing project having Parent already defined and declared. Parent class has got two constructors with initializer-list. This is my code, and it generates error C2668: 'Parent::Parent' : ambiguous call to overloaded function. Where is my error?

Thanks @Mape for your [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691616/5973613)

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Parent
{
public:
// Here a constructor with one default trailing argument, i.e. myInt,
// myDouble is not initialised. This is correct, as once one argument
// is initialised, the rule is that all the following ones have to be 
// initialised, but the previous ones may not be. 
Parent(double myDouble, int myInt=5);
// Here a defauls contructor, as all its arguments (one indeed) are 
// initialised
Parent(double myDouble=0);
double m_dVar;
int m_iVar;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
// derived class has to redefine the constructors. 
// Q1: All of them?
// Q2: With the same default arguments?
Child(double myDouble, int myInt=0);
Child(double myDouble=0);
}; 

class User
{
public:
User();
Parent* m_pGuy;
Child* m_pSonOfGuy;
};

// Base Class Implementation
Parent::Parent(double myDouble, int myInt)
{
    m_dVar=myDouble;
    m_iVar=myInt;
}

Parent::Parent(double myDouble)
{
    m_dVar=myDouble;
    m_iVar=3;
}

// Derived Class Implementation
// the two arguments contructor is easily implemented. 
Child::Child(double myDouble, int myInt)
   :   Parent(myDouble*2, myInt+1)
{
}
// the one argument contructor may trigger ERROR: 
// "ambiguous call to overloaded function."
// (C2668 in Microsoft Visual Studio compiler)
Child::Child(double myDouble)
    //:   Parent(0) ERROR
    :   Parent() //OK
{
    m_iVar=9;
}

User::User()
    :    m_pGuy(0) 
{  
}

// main{
int main(void)
{
   User user1();
   //Parent parent;
   Child child1(8.3,1);
   printf("\n\nChild  m_dVar %f",child1.m_dVar);
   printf("\nChild  m_iVar %d",child1.m_iVar);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler doesn't know which constructor you intend to call.
For example, your `Parent`class constructors, when called with one parameter, really have the same function signature.

```
Parent::Parent(double myDouble, int myInt=0) {
    cout << "Foo";
}
Parent::Parent(double myDouble) {
    cout << "Bar";
}

// later
Parent *parent = new Parent(1.2345);  // Compiler: which constructor to call?
                                      // does this mean Parent(1.2345, 0)
                                      // or Parent(1.2345)
```

Is this suppose to print Foo or Bar?

To make it work

- Change the code so that `myInt` parameter is not optional.

OR

- Remove the other constructor which only takes `myDouble` as parameter.

Comment: Thanks again Mape. I spent many hours to reduce the code to the minimal size to figure out where it was the true problem. No bad, as I learned something more about contructors. You here clearly confirmed it was due to the way we can call contructors with default arguments by omitting the default ones. I wonder where is the advantage to define contructors in the way I showed (I'm working on the Child side, the Parent one was already provided in a pre-existing project). Your suggestions above seem more functional. There may be a case in which the solution I posted may be useful in your opinion?

Comment: There shouldn't be any ambiguity between different constructors. There are probably better ways to organize the different constructors so that any combination of parameters is not ambiguous.

To me it seems, you really need to have a constructors `Parent(double)` and `Parent(double, int)` without any default values given for the parameters.

If you can't change the parent class, and it has those ambiguous constructors, then call them like you do now in your example, and fix the problem in Child by providing proper constructor(s) for it.